# Notation for counting measure in the case of two infinite sums, one being converted to an integral over $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: measure-theory, notation, lebesgue-integral

Using the properties of Lebesgue integration and the counting measure $\mu:\mathbb{N}\to [0,\infty]$ it can be shown that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^\infty g_{ij}\bigg) =  \sum_{j=1}^\infty\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^\infty g_{ij}\bigg),
$$
for every map $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to [0,\infty]:(i,j) \to g_{ij}$,

Let $g_{ij}:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to [0,\infty]:(i,j) \to g_{ij}$ be a map. Then we have,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}\bigg) & = \int_\mathbb{N}  \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} d\mu \\
& = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \int_\mathbb{N} a_{ij} d\mu \\
& =  \sum_{j=1}^\infty\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}\bigg).
\end{align*}
Is my notation correct for using the counting measure on the natural numbers?
In particular, how do we know that the integral over $\mathbb{N}$ is signifying that the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ should be fed into the $i$ component of the map $a_{ij}$?

Comment: Replace $d\mu$ by $d\mu(i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the counting measure as $\ \#: \>{\cal P}({\mathbb N})\to[0,\infty]$ and then write the integral as
$$s_i=\int_{\mathbb N} a_{ij}\>d\#(j)\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

It is implicit. For instance, when you integrate $f$ with respect to some measure $\mu$ as $\int f d\mu$, it is assumed that you are feeding the measure into the integrand.

So you can write this as 
$$\int_{\mathbb N} \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j d\mu$$

or 
$$\int_{\mathbb N} \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} d\mu(i).$$